# Create windows with lower opacity in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I try to create a translucent window with pyqt5. Instead of a window with with less opacity I got a window with no visible background.
Any ideas what I have to change?

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import Style

class Screen_Selector(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Screen_Selector, self).__init__()
        self.initUi()
        

    def initUi(self):
        # self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setGeometry(60,60,600,400)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.6)
        # self.hasMouseTracking = True
```

Comment: Try adding `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)` *after* setting `WA_TranslucentBackground`.

Comment: Try overriding [`QWidget::paintEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#paintEvent) and painting something simple -- filled rectangle etc.  I suspect the default implementation is a no-op -- hence the 'invisible' widget.

Comment: The `WA_TranslucentBackground` attribute causes the widget to have no background at all. When I remove that, the opacity works as expected.